# How to covert a string literal into an object cell range in python openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a cell range `temp == A23:C23` that I wanted to check if it is a subset of another.

The function `issubset()` can check whether one cell range is a subset of another.

My problem is that my other range is a string literal ie. `'A7:J22'`, so `temp.issubset('A7:J22')` does not work.

Is there a way that I can convert `'A7:J22'` into a cell Range `obj`?  Or another way of knowing whether my `temp` is a subset of this?

I can get all the valid addresses from `'A7:J22'` put them in a list, then do the same with `temp`.  But for a worksheet of over half a million cells, THAT'S A LOT!

Also tried manual comparison, ie evaluating the col and row values against the other.  But that's manual.  Hoping to find a more appropriate approach.

Comment: Show a reference to the function `issubset()`?

Comment: You can do this using the `CellRange` object in the worksheet package.